# Si da error quiero que vuelva a repetir la pregunta

Tags: python-3.x

Hola os pongo en contexto, estoy haciendo un programa que quiero que me pida por pantalla 2 números, uno será el dividendo y otro el divisor.

Quiero que si divisor es 0 quiero que me de un "error" y me vuelva a ejecutar el programa, tengo esto:

```
num2 = int(input("Dime el dividendo: "))
num1 = int(input("Dime el divisor: "))

if num1 <= 0:
    print("Bro, ¿Estás intentando dividir entre 0?")
else:
    print(num2 / num1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Cuando se trata de pedir y validar valores, lo mejor es usar un ciclo infinito y salir con un `break` cuando los valores sean válido. Esto evita tener que inicializar las variables y/o duplicar las instrucciones de E/S.

```
num2 = int(input("Dime el dividendo: "))

while True:
    num1 = int(input("Dime el divisor: "))
    if num1 <= 0:
        print("Error --> el número debe ser positivo. ")
        print("Bro, ¿Estás intentando dividir entre 0?")
    else:
        break

# num1 > 0    
print(num2 / num1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Vale, pues ya lo he conseguido, he usado la función while, os pongo el cacho de código que he añadido por si a alguien le interesa verlo.

```
num2 = int(input("Dime el dividendo: "))
num1 = int(input("Dime el divisor: "))

while num1<=0:
    print("Error --> el número debe ser positivo. ")
    num1 = int(input("Dime el divisor: "))
if num1 <= 0:
    print("Bro, ¿Estás intentando dividir entre 0?")
else:
    print(num2 / num1)
```

Comment: El `while` termina cuando `num1` es mayor que cero. Por tanto, el `if` está de más.

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma, en vez de pedir "permiso", sería pedir "perdón", que básicamente, significa, no controlar si el divisor es 0, sino actuar en caso que ocurra efectivamente la inválida división por 0.

```
num2 = int(input("Dime el dividendo: "))

while True:
  num1 = int(input("Dime el divisor: "))
  try:
    print(num2 / num1)
    break
  except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("Bro, ¿Estás intentando dividir entre 0?")
```

Esto implica controlar una excepción `ZeroDivisionError`, en caso que ocurra, se muestra el mensaje de error y se continua dentro del bloque `while`, si la división es válida, se muestra el resultado y se sale del `while`